# Axes label positions

Tags: pgfplots

I am using `pgfplots` to create simple theoretical graphs, so I use middle axis line style.  What bothers me is that

- x axis label is *above* instead of *below* or *right* of x axis and
- y axis label is *right* instead of *left* or *above* of y axis.

I have extensively studied pgfplots manual (I find it much more complex and disordered than `tikz` manual) and tried things to regulate this myself using stuff like `every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right)},anchor=north west}`, but to no avail.  How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{standard/.style={axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,enlarge x limits=0.15,enlarge y limits=0.15}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$v$,xtick={0,1.7},xticklabels={0,$t_1$},ytick={0,21},yticklabels={0,$v_0$}]
\addplot[thick,color=black] coordinates { (0,21) (1.7,21) (8.7,0) };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake I've rephrased.  IMHO pgfplots is fine package, so it would "deserve" better structured and clearer manual.

Comment: I still don't really see the point of putting that sentence into the question. It adds no value to the question, and it's unlikely to lead to better documentation for PGFplots. I think the constructive thing to do would be to remove the sentence and instead write an email to the PGFplots author Christian Feuersaenger, explaining what you think could be done to improve the documentation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You almost had it: The axis anchors you're looking for are called `current axis.right of origin` and `current axis.above origin`. The anchors are shown on the very simple and clear diagrams on pages 314-315 of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        enlarge x limits=0.15,
        enlarge y limits=0.15,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    standard,
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$v$,
    xtick={0,1.7},
    xticklabels={0,$t_1$},
    ytick={0,21},
    yticklabels={0,$v_0$}
]
\addplot[thick,color=black] coordinates { (0,21) (1.7,21) (8.7,0) };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed.  Believe or not I spent at least 1/2 hour searching and listing manual and did not find that page.