# How to create a graph with shaded region in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am looking to create the graph for the function `y = 1/x` for `x > 0`. The area under the curve between `x = a` and `x = 1` is `A1`. The area under the
curve between `x = 1` and `x = b` is `A2`.

I don't know how to shade the regions as shown in the figure.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the code to reproduce your graph (without the shading, of course, we will add it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of this is from the example on the bottom of p. 103 of the manual, and the positioning of `x` and `y` is from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68407/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=0.5;b=3;f(\x)=1/\x;}]
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
 xmin=-0.5,xmax=5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,ytick=\empty,
 xtick={a,1,b},xticklabels={$a$,$1$,$b$}, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68407/121799
 every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
 every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east}]
  \addplot[name path=A,blue,thick,domain=0.2:5,smooth] {f(x)};
  \path[name path=B] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  \addplot [gray!30] fill between [
        of=A and B,soft clip={domain=a:1},
    ];
    \addplot [gray] fill between [
        of=A and B,soft clip={domain=1:b},
    ];
    \path ({(1+a)/2},{f((1+a)/2)/2}) node{$A_1$}
    ({(1+b)/2},{f((1+b)/2)/2}) node{$A_2$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]